# The statement d = ('x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3) is showing errors in Python 3.6. What would be the correct syntax for the new version ?

Tags: python-3.6

It shows that Variable annotation cannot be combined with tuple unpacking.

Please tell me the correct syntax for Python 3.6

Comment: Please share the **exact** code that's producing the error. Because the statement you presented in the title is never valid in python!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax for an object is:

```
d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
```